# How to avoid overwriting a button text in java?

Tags: java, swing, random, overwrite

is it possible to avoid overwriting a button text. for example, in my program I have three buttons;

```
JButton button1 = new JButton();
JButton button2 = new JButton();
JButton button3 = new JButton();
```

Then I have a piece of code that randomly selects one of these buttons and write the given text/s on it, now I want is, once this code has chosen 1 button and written the text, I want it to not count this button in the next random selection or check if a certain text is already on the button then choose another button to write the text on.

```
String text = "text";
JButton[] arr = {button1, button2, button3};
Random r = new Random();
JButton b = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
b.setText(text);
b.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: You could use an array list instead of array and use `arraylist.remove(b);` to remove the already chosen button from the list.

Comment: could you please show me an  example, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list where you have the remaining buttons

```
List<JButton> remaining = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( arr ) );
```

Each time you set a text on a button remove that button from you list

```
void removeButton(JButton b, String text) {
  remaing.remove(b);
  b.setText(text);
  b.setEnabled(false);
}
```

then call random on the actual size

```
JButton b = remaining.get(r.nextInt(remaining.size()));
```

Comment: is it possible to check if the button to one of the two given text. e.g. check if the button text is not A or B and if its not then count that button in the random selection and if it is, then don't count that button.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error on the keyword List, List<JButton>

Comment: It's not a keyword it's an object: you have to import java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList

Use an editor like eclipse: it will propose you which imports correspond to your request

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a List containing your buttons.
2. You can use the Collections.shuffle() method to randomize the buttons.
3. Every time you need a random button you can access button(0) and then remove the button from the List.

Answer (score 0):

An if statement should work here:

```
String str = b.get Text();
if(str.size()==0){
    //Give text value 
}
```

Comment: is it possible to check if the button to one of the two given text. e.g. check if the button text is not A or B and if its not then count that button in the random selection and if it is, then don't count that button.

Comment: I believe the other answers have a much better implementation than mine! :)